# How to connect two different RESTful apis through mulesoft

Tags: java, rest, api, mule, mule-esb

I've got a question like in the title, because I have two RESTful applications:

- 1st is taking data from form and sending it to the other application using JSON
- 2nd is receiving data from the 1st application and making .csv from it

The question is how can I make a "connection" between them using mulesoft (got 30days free trial).

Comment: I dont know, have you tried reading the docs? What is the problem you are facing? This is a bit vague and badly spelled

Comment: I read a docs and dont even know how to start. Was trying to add flow in Anypoint studio but wasnt working for me. Sorry if its bad question., thats the 1st one.

Comment: Well by the looks of it with GET, POST, PUT, etc methods from the MuleSoft console.

Comment: I would just make a normal api call via http and if you really find any limitations there, you should consider using a framework that handles the communication. But I higly doubt it as for two services this is definitly overkill. As you pointed out, it looks like you do not know what your doing and adding more tech will not help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your requirements can be done in single flow. 
Use http to get data and then use transform message to convert that payload in csv.